# Pass input value to store using react-redux payload and reducer

Tags: react-native, react-redux, textinput, reducers

I have a Text Input and I am attempting to send the value inputted to the store in my reducer, then display that value on the screen.

It appears the input value is not even making it to the store...can someone explain why I am not dispatching this correctly?

e.target.value is throwing an error of Undefined.

COMPONENT

```
import React, { Component,setState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Text, StatusBar, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class Counter extends Component {

  emailHandler() {
      this.props.email();
  }

  toggleCounterHandler() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
       
        
        <View ><Text style={styles.welcometext}>{this.props.value}</Text></View>
        <View>
          
            <TextInput
             style={styles.input}
             onChangeText= {(e) => this.props.emailHandler(e.target.value)} 
             value={this.props.value}
             secureTextEntry={false}
             />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      value: state.value
    };
  }
  
  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      email: (value) => dispatch({
          type: 'email',
          payLoad: value
        })
      //() => dispatch({type: 'email', text: this.state.text})
    }
  };
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
```

REDUCER

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const counterReducer = (state = { email:'email' }, action) => {

  if (action.type === 'email') {
    return {
    ...state,
      email: action.payload,
    };
  }
  

console.log(state);
  return state;
};

const store = createStore(counterReducer);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at `onChangeText` api from the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext), it is passing the text straightaway as a param. Thus, you don't have to use `e.target.value`

Also second thing, I noticed that you `mapDispatchToProps` as `email` instead of `emailHandler`? So your redux function should be `this.props.email`

You don't have to create another function `emailHandler` to use the redux in props

you should do this:

```
import React, { Component,setState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Button, Text, StatusBar, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';


class Counter extends Component {


  toggleCounterHandler() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
       
        
        <View ><Text style={styles.welcometext}>{this.props.value}</Text></View>
        <View>
          
            <TextInput
             style={styles.input}
             onChangeText= {(e) => this.props.email(e.target.value)} 
             value={this.props.value}
             secureTextEntry={false}
             />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      value: state.value
    };
  }
  
  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      email: (value) => dispatch({
          type: 'email',
          payLoad: value
        })
      //() => dispatch({type: 'email', text: this.state.text})
    }
  };
  
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter);
```

Comment: I tried this and I received: "_this2.props.emailHandler is not a function." Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Do i need to put myText as an input received into emailHander(myText) {} ?

Comment: See the updated answer, your `mapDispatchToProps` is not `emailHandler`. You don't even have to create another function to do that, just pass it straightaway

Comment: so I would still call onChangeText= {(myText) => this.props.email(myText)}  then ?

Comment: I am receiving undefined as a value in my reducer when I am using the method provided. The errors are gone but it seems it's not dispatching the value.